# td width issue with text

Tags: html, tdd, html-table

Too much text is braking the width of the middle td. I thought that if you specified the width this should not be happening.

Any help?

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="541">

      <tr>
        <td background="images/left.png" width="20" height="313"><p>1</p></td>
        <td background="images/text_bg.png" width="501" height="313">
          <p>centasdfasfasfasfasfafasfasfasfasfasfjaslfashfalsjfhaskfjashfkasfjhaskjfhaskjfhasfkjashfasfgjasghasdgkljashgaksjlghasljkgher</p>
        </td>
        <td background="images/right.png" width="20" height="313"><p>3</p></td>
      </tr>

 </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that browser cannot split the word in p tag.
Usually you don't have such a long word. 
Just add space in the middle of your long text, and with of your td become normal.